# PHP - MySQLi Replace with Regex / Regexp / Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, mysqli

Sorry for that "Let me google that for you"-Question, but I can't find an answer.

I want to delete specfic elements from columns in my database. So I search with the following code for them: (it works fine)

```
    $sql = "SELECT list_id, list_domains
            FROM list
            WHERE list_domains REGEXP '[\s]*[a-z-]*\.[a-z/\.\?=]*.#".$number."#'";
        $result = $db->prepare( $sql );
        $result->execute();
        $result->bind_result( $list_id, $list_domains );
        $result->store_result();
```

Now I want to delete / replace the found elements inside these columns. So I use the following code:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE list
        SET list_domains = REPLACE(list_domains, '[\s]*[a-z-]*\.[a-z/\.\?=]*.#".$number."#', '')
        WHERE list_domains REGEXP '[\s]*[a-z-]*\.[a-z/\.\?=]*.#".$number."#'";
        $result = $db->prepare( $sql );
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();
```

Does not work. I also tried

```
REPLACE(list_domains, REGEXP '[\s]*[a-z-]*\.[a-z/\.\?=]*.#".$number."#', '')
```

or

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(list_domains, '[\s]*[a-z-]*\.[a-z/\.\?=]*.#".$number."#', '')
```

but these lines only produce errors.

How does it work to delete / replace specfic regular expressions with MySQLi?

Thanks for every suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REPLACE()` doesn't allow regular expression searching.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

If you want to manipulate strings with regex, `SELECT` the rows, do the manipulation in your own code, then issue an `UPDATE` statement to update the value, specifying the final value.